# Need Help Validating Textbox for Specific Length and content

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following validation code on my .asp webpage. I also need to validate the `txtndc` `textbox` so that the data entered looks like this.  **00000-0000**  Currently they can enter any info in this textbox.  The entry should always be 5 numbers a dash and 4 numbers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function form_onsubmit() {
    if (form1.txtdrug.value == "")
    {
        alert("Drug Name Needed");
        return false; 
    }

    if (form1.txtndc.value == "")
    {
        alert("NDC Number Needed");
        return false; 
    }

    if (form1.txtndc.value != "" && form1.txtdrug.value != "")
    {
        alert("Drug was Successfully entered into the database, hit enter to continue.");
        return true; 
    }
}
```

How would the syntax be written. The textbox i am trying to check is

```
<input type="text" name="txtndc" size="35">.
```

I am not sure how to enter your code below above into my page. Please Help

Comment: This is pure JavaScript, no Java and no ASP involved. Please tag properly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript regex#test function.

```
x = /^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/;     
console.log(x.test("12113-1234"));

>>> x = /^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/;    console.log(x.test("00000-0004")); 
true
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/axikiv/1/edit

Comment: How would the syntax be written.  The textbox i am trying to check is **<input type="text" name="txtndc" size="35">**.  I am not sure how to enter your code above into my page.